# Vertex pop-up menu openning when I try paste mesh in Edit mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Yesterday I was modelling and tried to copy a part of my mesh using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> buttons but suddenly I've pressed some other keys, and now when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> I get Vertex pop-up menu:

[image: Vertex pop-up]

Also there is the hint in Vertex column:

[image: Vertex column hint]

And if *Copy Attributes* add-on is enabled I get this pop-up menu when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keys:

[image: ctrl + c]

I reset the settings to default, removed all Blender instances, then istalled 3.6.5 version but nothing changed. In Object Mode copying-pasting through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> works fine.

Do you have some ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Actually this has been been for years now that `Ctrl`+`V` brings up the vertex menu in _Edit Mode_, just as `Ctrl`+`F` opens the face menu and `Ctrl`+`E` for the edge menu. It never worked to paste vertices as far as I know, and although using `Ctrl`+`C` does copy something in _Edit Mode_, the message at the bottom says "Copied 1 selected object(s)". And there it already indicates what it does, although in _Edit Mode_ it makes a copy of the whole object. Switch back to _Object Mode_ and press `Ctrl`+`V` and it will paste the complete object. But why not simply use _Duplicate_ (`Shift`+`D`)?

Comment: Thanks for reply Gordon. I seem you are right because I asked my friends to install a Blender instance and my issue reproduced. Maybe I used to use the other software for retopologizing... Actually I think I used Shift + D command. Thank you for answer and apologize for bothering...